# How to loop over modulus?

Tags: python, lcm

newbie here. I've been trying to find the least common multiple of the numbers 1 thru 10. My code so far

```
def smallest_multiple():
a = 0
while True:
    a += 1
    if a%1 == 0 and a%2 == 0 and a%3 == 0 and a%4 == 0 and a%5 == 0 and a%6 == 0 and a%7 == 0 and a%8 == 0 and a%9 == 0 and a%10 == 0:
        return a

print(smallest_multiple())
```

My result is 2520, which seems to be correct. It is the smallest number that is divisible by the numbers 1 thru 10 without remainder. But is there a way to make the 5 line shorter (not that much modulus) by iterating over them? I've tried something like this

```
def smallest_multiple():
a = 0
while True:
    a += 1
    for i in range(1, 11):
        if a % i == 0:
            return a

print(smallest_multiple())
```

But that returns just 1, not 2520. Is there a way to make

```
if a%1 == 0 and a%2 == 0 and a%3 == 0 and a%4 == 0 and a%5 == 0 and a%6 == 0 and a%7 == 0 and a%8 == 0 and a%9 == 0 and a%10 == 0:
```

shorter?

Comment: A suggestion: You can make your code a lot simpler, readable and efficient if you realize that `LCM(a, b, c) = LCM(LCM(a, b), c)` and `LCM(a, b) = (a * b) / GCD(a, b)` and use Euclidean algorithm for computing GCD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations

Answer (score 1):

You could change it to

```
if all([a%i == 0 for i in range(1,11)]):
```

All takes a list and returns True if everything in the list is True

This uses a simple list comprehension to go through numbers 1 through 10, and check if they are all True with `a%i == 0`

Comment: Why not use the result of the equality check directly? `if all(a%i == 0 for i in range(1,11)):`

Comment: `all([True for <anything>])` will always return true, because you're passing in a list of `True`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [all](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#all):

```
def smallest_multiple():
    factors = [i for i in range(1, 11)]
    a = 0
    while True:
        a += 1
        if all([a % factor == 0 for factor in factors]):
            return a


print(smallest_multiple())
```

**Output**

```
2520
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @PatrickHaugh you can avoid the creation of lists:

```
def smallest_multiple():
    factors = range(1, 11)
    a = 0
    while True:
        a += 1
        if all(a % factor == 0 for factor in factors):
            return a


print(smallest_multiple())
```

**Output**

```
2520
```

Comment: You're building a few unnecessary lists here. Why are you making `factors` a lit when you can already iterate over a `range`?  You also don't need to make a list of your divisibility checks: if you use a generator expression `all(a % factor == 0 for factor in factors)` then `all` won't have to calculate all of the items if one of them is not equal to 0

Comment: you are unnesesarely making the range each time you need it. Patrick Haugh did not mean you shouldm't bring it out of the loop, just that the lis comprehension wasn't smart.

Comment: @JonasWolff fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of one-liners ^^

Not an Infinity loop, though

```
import sys
next(i for i in xrange(1, sys.maxsize) if len([j for j in range(1,10) if i % j == 0]) == 9)
#=> 2520
```

And this is not the most efficient solution.